# Archive old files

Tags: svn

I am new to SVN.  I have a lot of old, unused files that I want to archive or copy to a different repository or directory.  How can I archive these files and keep the history of their revisions?

Answer (score 3):

- `svn move` if you want them in a different directory. You can sill access the file's history.
- `svn delete` if you want some kind of archive. It's there in the older revision but they're gone in newer ones. Of course, the file's history is untouched.

Answer (score 2):

Just delete them. History will remain and you won't have a bunch of files occupying space and fragmenting your HD.

Answer (score 2):

You can always create a new repository for you new revisions. 
Just use "svnadmin dump" and "svnadmin load" for your revisions.
You will have your old revisions in the first repository, and you can start fresh in a new one.

Comment: That should probably be `svnadmin dump` and `svnadmin load`, respectively.

Answer (score 2):

svn delete will work, but since I don't know of the best way to quickly get at the project's history, I always move it into a folder at the same level as /trunk and /branches, like /archives so it is simpler to find later, but also doesn't get downloaded when I check the trunk out to a different machine (or on the build server).